# jQueryUI: animate parent element height on child animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

When I hide a child element using jQuery UI `.hide('slide', {direction:'up'})` animation I would like to animate its parent's height as well.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BG4Hk/2/) is an example of what I have. The animation doesn't look so well because parent's height is changed right after its child gets hidden, not in a process, as in jQuery `.slideUp()` animation.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly changed up your CSS as follows and it looks pretty good.  A bit of fooling around and it should look exactly like what you want.

```
#container{
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    height:auto;
}

#child{
    background-color:blue;
    border:10px solid #red;
    border-top:0px;
}

#content{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I call it cheating: parent element animation is still the same. I gave this css just for a example, real case is much more complicated than this and I wish I could fix it as easy as you did.

Comment: Could you share more code?  It's more helpful to know exactly what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** some tweaks :) Tested: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/BG4Hk/16/

Try something like this:

```
var original_height = 0;

$('#child').click(function() {
    if (!original_height) {
        original_height = $(this).height();
    }
    $(this).stop().animate({'height': 0}, 1000, function() { $(this).hide(); });
});

$('#content').click(function() {
    if (original_height) {
        $('#child').stop().show().animate({'height': original_height}, 1000);
    }
});
```

It needs a bit more work, to handle loose ends, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks, but it is exactly what `.slideUp()` does, I would like to stick with the slide animation, that's the only reason I don't use `.slideUp()`.

Comment: SlideUp() has a drawback: when the animation starts, it keeps the original object dimensions intact, and adjusts the surroundings (parent size) after the animation finished. This is your problem in the first place. With animation() the object is beeing resized, with the surroundings updating instantly.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is jQuery `.animate({'height': 0})`/`.slideUp()` animation is not the same as jQuery UI `.hide('slide', {direction:'up'})`. Also in the example given in the topic, `.slideUp()` acts exactly as `.animate({'height': 0})`, so that has never been my problem in the first place.

Comment: Also, don't know what browser you are using to see that "drawback" on `.slideUp()`, but this example http://jsfiddle.net/BG4Hk/21/ works just fine in IE 7/8, FF 3.6, Chrome 7.